# Please explain this algorithm from Code Jam 2009 

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, breadth-first-search

This is problem from [round 1B 2009 Problem C "Square Math"](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=186264#s=p2). I know contest analysis is posted. But I am not getting on how to implement BFS when a node can be visited more than once. I could only implement using DFS. (because context is saved implicitly in recursive DFS). How to do that using BFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the context explicitly.

For each number cell, keep a table of all totals that can be produced by paths of length N ending at that cell and, for each total, the best path that produces it.

For N=1, this data is easily produced (one trivial path for each cell) and given the tables for a given N, you can produce the tables for the next larger N pretty easily by extending each path.

Comment: Thnx. Thats a very good algo. Is it doing BFS in a different way ?

Comment: It's still called breadth-first search. Keeping track of all the loose ends is a little more complicated, that's all.